# Is chat.stackoverflow.com off-the-shelf or in-house built?

Tags: discussion, chat

Just wondering if anyone knows if chat.stackoverflow.com is built in-house or is making use of an off the shelf product (and if so which one).

Comment: Does software still come on shelves? :)

Comment: Unless you go commando, yes. @bal

Comment: Quite literally [in-house](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/welcome-stack-overflow-valued-associates-00006-and-00007/), I believe :)

Comment: @Balpha In Russia and eastern Europe, it is actually *hard* to find legitimate software (and China, I gather).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's built in house.

I was going to list the developers but being afraid of offending by missing someone out I decided not to.

Comment: The developer was *balpharc*.

Comment: @Lady good thing you didn't say malpha, that *would* have offended me.

Comment: @balpha: I'll keep that in mind :]

Comment: @balpha How about Mr. Grumke? :D

Answer (score 5):

In house, with the [standard tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-were-used-to-build-the-trilogy)

Comment: Standard tools: Coffee, donuts and an aversion to shaving.

Comment: @webbiedave - not an active *aversion* so much; more... apathy and indifference